# Which is the role of Algebraic Geometry in String Theory?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, soft-question, mathematics, algebraic-geometry

Could someone sketch me what [algebraic geometry has to do with string theory](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=string+theory&as_epq=algebraic+geometry)? 
Are there other mathematical disciplines that are interwoven with string theory?

I'm aware of [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59740/) on math.stackexchange. But this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This seems awfully broad. Can you pin down what you're trying to establish? For example, are you asking what you should read up on to start learning string theory?

Comment: I tried to look it up. The answer to first question may be: [homological mirror symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_mirror_symmetry), and the answer to the second question may be: [symplectic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry). I have no idea what either is (about). :)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2528/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry) (along with almost any discipline of mathematics, even [number theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=number+theory)) appears in many corners of [string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) and other areas of physics, possibly too many to list.

E.g. typically the 6 compact dimensions of the 10-dimensional (super) string is taken to be a [Calabi-Yau manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4972/2451) Phys.SE and links therein. Perhaps one of the more abundant sources of algebraic geometry is [type IIA and type IIB string theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_II_string_theory), which are interwoven by [mirrorsymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_symmetry_%28string_theory%29).

Comment: You could also add the statement that sheaves are used to represent D-branes in string theory, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Sanath Devalapurkar: Good point.