# Mathematical books to become a successful mathematical physicists

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

My understanding of algebraic topology and Riemannian geometry come from Nakahara's *Geometry, Topology, and Physics,* which I do not think is sufficient. I am first year PhD student, and I want to do string theory at my university. Can you recommend me any other really nice books that I should read over the years.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Should I delete the post? However, I have heard of or skimmed through many of the books that are in that post. None of them seem to be algebriac geometry books... So maybe some people can give me some recommendations in this area too?

Comment: There is also this one: [Book recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/) which suggests this one: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2528/

Comment: Should I delete the post if it is deemed duplicate?