# Resources for algebraic topology in condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, topology

I wanted to know if anyone had any good introductions on algebraic topology for the theoretical physicist? I am particularly interested in applications to condensed matter physics, but would be happy with any kind of resource -- all my friends and I can find are the more abstract mathematical textbooks and articles.

In terms of relevant background, I am looking for something that assumes basic knowledge of quantum theory, quantum field theory, solid state physics, group theory, abstract algebra, and real analysis.

Comment: You might be interested in this upcoming edx course.
https://www.edx.org/course/topology-condensed-matter-tying-quantum-delftx-topocmx-0

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2528/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The books of [Nakahara](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068) and [Frenkel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602) are two physicists' books that come to mind. Charles Kane himself recommended Nakahara very warmly to physicsts, saying he had studied all he knows about topology from that book.

Personally I prefer the simpler math books. One of which is [Bredon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387979263)'s.

Answer (score 5):

The book by Nakahara, as mentioned in its description, is intended for students of particle physics, gravitation & cosmology, and solid state physics. It covers algebraic topology in its first few chapters at a level that is relatively adequate for a physicist. The few knowledgeable people I asked recommended it as a good starting point for topology, and algebraic topology in particular.